# Behavior of the period map at the boundary of the Teichmuller space

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, teichmuller-theory

Fix a compact oriented surface $S$ of genus $g$. Any complex structure $J$ on $S$ gives by the Hodge decomposition a linear complex structure $J'$ on $H_1(S,\mathbb{R})$. The map $J\mapsto J'$ is a period map from the Teichmüller space to the Siegel upper half-space. Is it possible to extend this map to the/some compactifications of both spaces?

For instance, if $J_n$ converges to some (non-orientable) projective measured lamination, does $J'_n$ converge to some real Lagrangian in $H_1(S,\mathbb{R})$ (or some more complicated object)?

Comment: There is a Satake compactification of the period domain, and the Torelli map extends as a holomorphic map to the Satake compactification from the Deligne-Mumford compactification of the moduli space of genus $g$ Riemann surfaces.

Comment: The Deligne-Mumford compactification corresponds to the “augmented Teichmueller space” of Hubbard and Koch.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree that the extension of the period map to the augmented Teichmüller space is rather natural. However, I have no clue for the extension to the Thurston compactification (but I am far from specialist).